# DispatchTimer not stopping when navigated to the next page.

Tags: timer, uwp

I have implemented timers behind my pages so that if the system is inactive, it will be navigated back to my HomePage, however, one of my pages's timer isnt working.

It doesnt seem to stop ticking after I navigated to the next page. I have placed my codes below on how I wrote the timer.

**OnLoadState:**

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // reload the timer from MainPage shell
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.NavigationParameter as MainPage != null)
            {
                MainPage page = e.NavigationParameter as MainPage;
                this.idleTimer = page.idleTimer;
                idleTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                idleTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

**OnNavigatedFrom**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        MainPage a = new MainPage();
        idleTimer.Stop();
        idleTimer.Tick -= a.idleTimer_Tick;
        //try
        //{
        //    if (dialogTimer != null)
        //        dialogTimer.Stop();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{ }
    }
```

And my button click event to navigate to the **next page**.

```
private void WebViewContactButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        idleTimer.Stop();
        var rootFrame = (Window.Current.Content as Frame);
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "SMS");

    }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete -- eg you don't show where you add the event handler. It is *very* suspicious that you create a dummy `MainPage` and then try to remove the event handler (that won't do anything BTW).

Comment: Oh I have a MainPage, which acts as a Frame for my pages.... the rest of the pages's Dispatcher Timer does work... but only this page....

Comment: Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. You don't need to include the .csproj etc. but do create the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem (often this will solve it for you) and post that.